# Dart `pubspec.yaml`: Have one part of the package use Flutter without the whole package depending on Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I'm trying to create a package that works across `Flutter`, `Web`, and `Other` on pub.dart.org. As long as the default file in the package does not have platform dependencies, other files can do so without causing the whole package to be platform dependent. This works when one file uses `dart:io` and another uses `dart:html`, as long as the default import does not do that.

However, adding any sort of dependency on Flutter, say because there's a single file in the package that uses it, causes pub.dart.org to list the package as `Flutter` only.

I believe it has something to do with the fact Flutter actually requires an SDK in `pubspec.yaml`, but I haven't been able to find any further information about this.

Comment: Instead of having one package, you should have 3. One for the core implementation that takes interfaces. One implementation of these interfaces for the web. And another for flutter.

Comment: But currently there are two: web/other can share but Flutter cannot. There should be some resolution to this I'd think. Is there some official recommendation to do it as you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because web/io and Flutter use different Dart SDKs this causes troubles.
If  `pubspec.yaml` contains

```
flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
```

the non-Flutter `pub` tool will reject the package.

You can try to leave that out from the shared package.

If that doesn't work, you need to extract the libraries that depend directly on the Flutter SDK into a separate package.

Comment: Flutter's Dart SDK still gets chosen because it's a transient dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. For example, if you look at the [password](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/password) plugin, you can see that it is usable on Flutter, Web, and Other, so you just have to make sure that your dependencies are common among all three and you should be good to go! If there is an issue about putting it on the pub.dart.org, you can first try to transfer your files from flutter to dart, along with your pubspec.yaml and all your other files and try to put it on now.